# removes any cover for Republicans

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Does "cover" here mean "protection/shelter" or "concealment"? Or does it simply mean "excuse"?

> The vote also largely **removes any cover for Republicans** in Congress who for six weeks have largely refused to acknowledge Mr. Biden as the president-elect. In providing Mr. Trump the room to dispute his loss, staying largely silent as he peddled conspiracy theories about voting fraud, they had presented the Electoral College as the new marker for when a presidential victory should be recognized.

> Source: [NYTimes](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/12/14/us/politics/biden-electoral-college.html)

Answer (score 3):

Cover here does mean "protection" in a somewhat metaphorical sense, derived from the "cover" that that a soldier would seek if they are under fire.

> Find some cover quickly, there are enemy gunners on the hills opposite.

Cover might be bushes or rocks that the soldier can hide behind.

In the metaphorical sense Republicans have been able to hide their opinions behind the "cover" of saying "we have to wait for the electoral college vote.  Now that the college has voted they either have to publically agree with Trump that the election was rigged (for many this is an extremist position) or publically disagree with him. There is nothing to hide behind.